# How can I specify https protocol in routing spec with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, specifications

In my routes file I have:

```
resources :subscription, :only => [:show], :constraints => {:protocol => "https"}
```

I'm trying to add a spec for this route like this:

```
it "recognizes and generates #show" do
  { :get => "/subscription", :protocol => 'https' }.should route_to(:controller => "subscriptions", :action => "show")
end
```

However, the spec still fails. 
If I remove the `:protocol => 'https'`, the spec also fails:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:    
  No route matches "/subscription"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (undocumented?) solution is to simply include an entire dummy url, like so:

```
it "recognizes and generates #show" do
  { :get => "https://test.host/subscription" }.should route_to(:controller => "subscriptions", :action => "show")
end
```

I figured it out from [this ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/5805-assert_recognizes-does-not-support-constraints) and [this changeset](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e9ae88af2038f4d29e437a937f2ce63ffd935d5f).

Comment: In order to get this to work I had to specify the constraint as `{ protocol => "https://" }`, not simply `"https"` as one might expect.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I think routes should be declared as plural — see [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). So it would be

```
resources :subscriptions
```

and in the spec

```
{:get => '/subscriptions', :protocol => 'https'}
```

Try if that passes without `:protocol`. If it does, skip the spec with HTTPS. That should not be tested on a unit-test level, but in an integration test.

Comment: I'm using 'subscription' as a singular resource. See section 2.5 in the guide you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think of that. I've added another answer.

Answer (score -1):

Does it pass if you change to spec to this?:

```
{:get => '/subscription'}.should_not route_to(:controller => …)
```

That would at least give you the confidence that HTTP is not routed.