# Rspec testing conditional routing constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, capybara

I'm trying to write some rspec integration tests to test that my conditional routes are routing correctly, but I'm getting a bunch of problems.

In routes.rb:

```
root :to => "error#ie6", :constraints => {:user_agent => /MSIE 6/}
root :to => "protocol_sets#index", :constraints => UserRoleConstraint.new(/doctor/i)
root :to => "refill_requests#create", :constraints => UserRoleConstraint.new(/member/i)
root :to => "refill_requests#create", :constraints => {:subdomain => "demo"}
root :to => "site#index"
```

In spec/requests/homepage_routing_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User Visits Homepage" do
  describe "Routings to homepage" do
    it "routes / to site#index when no session information exists" do
      visit root_path      
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error when I try to run the test.

```
Failures:

  1) User Visits Homepage Routings to homepage routes / to site#index when no session information exists
     Failure/Error: visit root_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
     # :10:in `synchronize'
     # ./spec/requests/homepage_routings_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.08088 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/homepage_routings_spec.rb:5 # User Visits Homepage Routings to homepage routes / to site#index when no session information exists
```

From Googling around I'm guessing there may be a problem with how rspec/capybara handle conditional routes.

Is there anyway to test constraints on routes with rspec and capybara?

Answer (score 1):

As this drove me nuts over the last days, I found the solution with the help of a colleague.

When using named route constraints, like `UserRoleConstraint` in the example, I resorted to actually stubbing the `matches?` method of the constraint int he specs that needed it, i.e.:

```
describe 'routing' do
  context 'w/o route constraint' do 
    before do
      allow(UserRoleConstraint).to receive(:matches?).and_return { false }
    end

    # tests without the route constraint
  end
  context 'w/ route constraint' do 
    before do
      allow(UserRoleConstraint).to receive(:matches?).and_return { true }
    end
  end

  # tests with the route constraint
end
```

Note that this requires you to have named constraints, which might not apply to your case.

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you find a better solution by now?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I think this actually should be `allow_any_instance_of(UserRoleConstraint).to receive(:matches?).and_return { true }`

Answer (score 0):

For the protocol constraint you can just specify an entire url with dummy domain. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254801/168143).